# Black screen with Linux kernel 3.19.0.41

Tags: boot, keyboard, kernel

I have a PC with elementary OS only and after loading screen and elementary logo there is just a black screen instead of login screen. My keyboard acts like it's unplugged, it doesn't respond to num lock or scroll lock or caps lock button, all diodes are off. HDD led in my pc doesn't show any hard drive actions. When I boot up with the Linux kernel 3.19.0.39 everything works just fine. How can I diagnose what's going on, or how can I try to fix the newer kernel?

Comment: boot to `3.19.0.41` recovery mode and select `resume normal reboot` and let me know ;)

Comment: I have a black screen in recovery mode too, but with blinking underscore character in the top-left corner

Comment: Ok i figured it out. NVIDIA drivers was causing this problem. Reinstallation didn't help, but remove with --purge flag and new installation did. Thanks for help anyway

Comment: Please post it as answer :)

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver) if useful :)

Answer (score 2):

NVIDIA drivers were causing the problem. I removed drivers completely with --purge flag and then installed current drivers again and now everything works. 
Here's how to do this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver